# How to drag and drop table rows to swap them using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to swap table rows using JQuery UI. It works well but I just could not get the row number during the drag and drop event. I need to know the row number for my following work, could someone help me?

eg.

```
$('#table1 tbody').sortable({
revert: true,
start: function(event, ui) {
    // get row number, such as (row) 1
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    // get row number, such as (row) 3
}});
```

In fact, I do not need to sort table rows (just swap), if there are any possible solutions, please let me know...

Comment: please put your question properly ... on start and on stop row number will remain same ... how it can be different ?why you want to know on start as well as on stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stop event you can get row number of drag-gable rows.

```
 stop: function(ui, event){
        var id = event.item.index();
        alert(id);
    }
```

Try this

### JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vn5SZ/31/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the tr elements inside `tbody`
Add a helper clone when dragging a tr. Only way you can make the drag.

When the dragging starts, a clone is made (because of helper: "clone") and the `c variable` will hold reference to the clone and the tr being dragged. When the dragging stops, if it is outside a droppable, the clone is destroyed. If it is inside the draggable, we destroy the clone and the tr (so it is removed from the list and can't be dragged again)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to get the row number on start and stop since it will be same .

and to know the row number just give data attribute to your rows as:

```
data-rownumber=1
```

than try this

```
$('#table1 tbody').sortable({
revert: true,

stop: function(event, ui) {
    var row=ui.draggable.attr('data-rownumber'); 
//this will be the dragged row id
}});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.